# On average, what percentage of 6-digit licence plates contain the numbers '7' or '8'?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How to I solve this math question?

Number of license plate = 10^6

but I'm confused with the number of possible cases

You can have one '7' at 6 different places
Then two '7' in 15 different cases C(6,2)
Then three '7' in XX different case...

Same logic with '8'
And a different logic with both '7' and '8'

But I have a hard time to figure out how to combine those logics to get the total number of possible cases.

Any help?

Comment: This is easiest to do by looking at the complement.  How many *don't* have a '7' or '8'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first digit has a $\frac{8}{10}$ chance of **not** being a $7$ or $8$. The same goes for for the second, etc.

The chance that a number doesn't have any $7$ or $8$s at all is the combined chance that all digits are not a $7$ or $8$, this gives $\left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^6$.

Now the chance that a license plate *does* contain a $7$ or $8$ is simply $1 - \left(\frac{8}{10}\right)^6 = 73.7856\%$.